# Google Cloud : Remove account form google-sudoers

Tags: linux, ssh, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I desired to give an access to dev team, so I created 'tempuser' and then cmd to grant ssh connection following

```
tempuser@instance-1:~$ gcloud compute ssh tempuser@instance-1
```

It worked well, but It also added this "tempuser" to google-sudoers group which gave it the full access to all folder as below

```
uid=1003(tempuser) gid=1004(tempuser) groups=1004(tempuser),4(adm),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),1000(google-sudoers)
```

After I tried to manually remove tempuser from google-sudoers by this cmd,

```
deluser tempuser google-sudoers
```

it did effect for a short period and then it would automatically be restored 'tempuser' to be a member of google-sudoers again by some script from google I guess.

As this violate security rule, Could anyone tell me how I can remove user 'tempuser' from google-sudoers

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you still encountering any issues? Did you try to use the Identity and Access Management Roles, however some roles are still in Beta? More information is available here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue with George's suggestion? If yes, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, can you provide more information as to further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if you have [User Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/) feature setup in your project. If so, you need to remove the user account using your [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/useraccounts/accounts?_ga=1.176766117.1639157526.1480960431) or [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/users/delete) command. The user accounts created in your project will be propagated to all the VMs with the permissions that you assigned.